# How to efficiently find all matches of an subarray in another array?

Tags: c, arrays, search, optimization

For example this is the way I have implemented it now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

size_t *find_matches(char *needle, size_t needleSize, char *haystack, size_t haystackSize, size_t *size) {
    size_t max_matches = 256;
    size_t *matches = malloc(sizeof(size_t) * max_matches);
    int matchCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i + needleSize <= haystackSize; i++) {
        bool matched = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < needleSize; j++) {
            if(haystack[i + j] != needle[j]) {
                matched = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(matched) {
            matches[matchCount] = i;
            matchCount++;
            if(matchCount == max_matches) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    *size = matchCount;
    return matches;
}

int main() {
    char needle[] = {0xed, 0x57, 0x35, 0xe7, 0x00};
    char haystack[] = {0xed, 0x57, 0x35, 0xe7, 0x00, ..., 0xed, 0x57, 0x35, 0xe7, 0x00, ...};
    size_t size;
    size_t *matches = find_matches(needle, sizeof(needle), haystack, sizeof(haystack), &size);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Match %zi: %zi\n", i, matches[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can this not be optimized more?

Comment: [Rabin–Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)?

Comment: This is called string searching.  There are many algorithms to make this more efficient although they can be somewhat complex.

Comment: @VaughnCato Why creating a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze cc to you :-)

Comment: @junix Aye, aye, cap! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Rabin–Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) and others ([Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), [Boyer–Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)).

Comment: I found this implementation of Rabin-Karp in C: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-3-rabin-karp-algorithm/ however it fails with: `pattern="\xff"; text="\x00\xff"`. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Think. Strings are NUL-terminated, what is `strlen("\x00\xff")`?

Comment: @Alexey_Frunze Sorry, I forgot to say I replaced the `strlen` for both `N` and `M` with parameters to the function. It still doesn't find it. Like so: http://pastebin.com/iwVGymQg

Comment: Debug the code. You should be able to do it if you understand the algorithm and know how to use a debugger.

Comment: @Alexey_Frunze it was due to the checking for negative values of `t`, because the `chars` aren't unsigned, right?